# Force show keyboard doesn't work unless you run in background thread

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

Here's the project showing what works and what doesn't.  Code is also below.  I've found many stackoverflow posts showing the clear solution for this, but for some reason that doesn't work for me unless I run it in a background thread.

I'm creating an AlertDialog and an EditText.  My goal is to show the alert dialog, show keyboard, and have cursor in the edit text.  For some reason, I cannot just RequestFocus and ShowSoftInput.  It only works when I create a background thread, then make the call...  Why is that?  Am I doing something wrong?

[image] [image]

Here's a screenshot of what the app looks like when I run the code in the background thread vs not...

Link to Xamarin Android project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5x7JEZ8aQihVnM4am8yRWlQYkU

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };



        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
        TextView titleTV = new TextView(this);
        titleTV.Text = "title";
        titleTV.TextSize = 18f;
        titleTV.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        titleTV.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        titleTV.SetPadding(0, 12, 0, 12);
        titleTV.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal | GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
        alertBuilder.SetCustomTitle(titleTV);

        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.SetHeight(600); 
        editText.Text = "super coooool dude";
        editText.TextSize = 14f;
        editText.SetPadding(18, 12, 18, 12);
        editText.Gravity = GravityFlags.Left | GravityFlags.Top;
        editText.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = true;
        editText.RequestFocus();
        alertBuilder.SetView(editText);
        alertBuilder.SetPositiveButton("Done", (sender, e) => { });
        alertBuilder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender, e) => { });

        alertDialog = alertBuilder.Create();
        alertDialog.Show();



        // STACKOVERFLOW LOOK HERE.  

        //// Calling ForceShowKeyboard does not work here..... Why?  
        //this.ForceShowKeyboard(editText);

        // But, calling ForceShowKeyboard works when in a background thread, sleeping a bit, then run on main thread again
        Thread t = new Thread(() => this.DoThreadSTuff(editText));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void DoThreadSTuff(EditText editText)
    {
        // I dont think a sleep is needed, but i found a similar issue in Xamarin.iOS once upon a time, and a sleep was needed.  It seems Xamarin.Android doesn't require a sleep though.  
        //Thread.Sleep(2);

        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            this.ForceShowKeyboard(editText);
        });
    }

    private void ForceShowKeyboard(EditText editText)
    {
        editText.RequestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.ShowSoftInput(editText, ShowFlags.Implicit);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the keyboard do not show when you call `this.ForceShowKeyboard(editText);` directly.

You can find the dialog source code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Dialog.java), when you show a dialog, it will send a `SHOW` message to handler ,and then let UI thread to show a dialog.

```
   public void show() {

       ......

        sendShowMessage();
    }

   private void sendShowMessage() {
        if (mShowMessage != null) {
            // Obtain a new message so this dialog can be re-used
            Message.obtain(mShowMessage).sendToTarget();
        }
    }

    .....
    mShowMessage = mListenersHandler.obtainMessage(SHOW, listener);


   private static final class ListenersHandler extends Handler {
   ......
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            ......
            case SHOW:
                ((OnShowListener) msg.obj).onShow(mDialog.get());
                break;
        }
     }
   }
```

**So `Dialog.Show()` is asynchronous method.**

That means `this.ForceShowKeyboard(editText);` will be called before dialog show. So you can not see the keyboard.

> Why the keyboard show  when I run the code in the background thread.

You call `RunOnUIThread()` in another thread. The delegate of `RunOnUIThread` will be posted to the event queue of the UI thread. That means it will run when you dialog created. So you can see the keyboard.

By checking the source code of `RunOnUIThread()` it is a also a handler.

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
        if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
            mHandler.post(action);
        } else {
            action.run();
        }
    }
```

In other words when your dialog created it will send a message to UI thread handler, and the handler will make `EditText` focus.

Get the knowledge of Android Handler it will help you to understand.